# Screen goes black when trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, hp, re-installation

Trying to re-install Ubuntu 11.10 on an HP Pavilion G6. Screen goes black after the Ubuntu logo shows. How do I get it to install normally?

Installed Ubuntu 11.10 successfully without my wireless device being recognized. Used `sudo apt-get update + upgrade` commands to attempt to fix this. Computer crashes after upgrade and now it won't finish re-installing Ubuntu. After it shows the first purple screen with the Ubuntu logo, the screen goes black.

Used the *Darik's Boot and Nuke* CD and then attempted re-installation again, and the black screen problem remains consistent, seemingly no matter what I do. It sounds like it's installing but won't let me see anything or go anywhere.

Comment: apt-get update and apt-get upgrade are not Magic commands that fix everything, they serve two purposes, updating the repositories and upgrading packages, they don't *fix* anything but and outdated system. Now the proper way to  *install* Ubuntu is to create a LiveCD/USB/DVD and follow the steps on the Installer, when reinstalling you don't need any extra tools other than the same media you used to install.

Comment: Now IIRC the black screen is due to the graphics drivers. Also.. it's Ubuntu 11. **10** not 11.1

Comment: Have you tried this, after boot keep your finger on the “SHIFT” key till you get the grub menu. Highlight the first entry and replace “quiet splash” with “nomodeset” .  Hit CTRL + X to continue booting. Once logged in install the latest Graphics drivers. System -> Administration -> Additional Drivers

Comment: well *uri herrera* 11.10 and 11.1 mean the same thing and I know the upgrade doesn't fix everything, I just thought they might've updated the system to read some certain device thanks for the help, i know how to install an operating system I work at a tech collective

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. I changed it to nomodeset but I had to get there differently. There was no grub menu showing up for some reason. So when the ubuntu screen showed up before the black screen, I hit F6 and went to *other options* and changed it to nomodeset, then I installed and it works great now.